# Return row of Data Frame based on value in a column. R script

Tags: r

My script reads an .xlsx worksheet and create a .pdf file with the I chart, MR chart and capacity graph of numbers of defects of the last 40 rows. The spreadsheet have 2 columns, the first with the material number and the second with the number of defects.

I want to change the script so that the user writes the material number (`cat` command) and the system draws the graphics based on their respective number of defects.

Example:

The user types the numbers 5, 1, 3 and 8 and script will creat a new table call "Data1" with the material number and it's respective defects (1198, 1201, 1204, 1201).

```
Number  Defect
5       1198
1       1201
3       1204
8       1201
```

The part of graphics is already done.
I tried create a data frame to collect the data created by the `cat` command but I do not know How to correlate it with the worksheet. I tried using `which` and `subset` but without success.

Could you help me?

Thank you very much.

Best regards.

---

### Code before changes.

```
cat("\f")

#install.packages(c("qcc", "openxlsx"))
library(qcc)
library(openxlsx)

qcc.options(bg.margin = "white")

#-----------------------------------------------
cat("How many sigmas do you want use for your calculus?")
NSigmas <- scan(n = 1)
`Significant algharisms`<-5

#----------------------------------------------------------------
#Control chart

Spreadsheet1 <- read.xlsx("Chord height at R42000.xlsx", sheet = "BD", 
    startRow = 1, colNames = TRUE)
Data1 <- tail(Spreadsheet1, 40)
`Chord height at R42000` <- Data1$Defect

pdf("Finish - Chord height at R42000.pdf", paper = "a4r", width = 21 / 2.54, 
    height = 29.7 / 2.54, title = "Finish - Chord height at R42000.pdf")

`I1 chart` <- qcc(`Chord height at R42000`, type = "xbar.one", nsigmas = (NSigmas/2), 
    xlab = "Observations", ylab = "Indivudual values", title = "I Chart", 
    digits = `Significant algharisms`)
`Y axis MR1` <- matrix(cbind(`Chord height at R42000`[1:length(`Chord height at R42000`)-1], 
    `Chord height at R42000`[2:length(`Chord height at R42000`)]), ncol = 2)
`MR chart` <- qcc(`Y axis MR1`, type = "R", nsigmas = (NSigmas / 2), xlab = "Observations", 
    ylab = "Moving range", title = "Moving range Chart", digits = `Significant algharisms`)
CapabilidadeI1 <- process.capability(`I1 chart`, spec.limits = c(1198, 1211), 
    nsigmas = (NSigmas / 2), target = ((1198 + 1211) / 2))

dev.off()
```

---

### Code after changes. Please uncomment if you want test using "subset" ou "which".

```
cat("\f")

#install.packages(c("qcc", "openxlsx"))
library(qcc)
library(openxlsx)

qcc.options(bg.margin = "white")

#-----------------------------------------------
cat("How many sigmas do you want use for your calculus?")
NSigmas <- scan(n = 1)
cat("What materials would you like to evaluate? Exit pressing enter twice.")
Materials<-scan()
Materials2<-data.frame(Materials)
`Significant algharisms` <- 5

#----------------------------------------------------------------
#Control chart

Spreadsheet1 <- read.xlsx("Chord height at R42000.xlsx", sheet = "BD", 
    startRow = 1, colNames = TRUE)

# Data1<-Spreadsheet1[which(Spreadsheet1[,1]==Materials2[,1]),]
# Data1<-subset(Spreadsheet1, Spreadsheet1$Number==Materials2$Materials)

## The variable don't store all numbers I type with "cat" command.

`Chord height at R42000` <- Data1$Defect

pdf("Finish - Chord height at R42000.pdf", paper = "a4r", width = 21 / 2.54, 
    height = 29.7 / 2.54, title = "Finish - Chord height at R42000.pdf")

`I1 chart` <- qcc(`Chord height at R42000`, type = "xbar.one", nsigmas = (NSigmas/2), 
    xlab = "Observations", ylab = "Indivudual values", title = "I Chart", 
    digits = `Significant algharisms`)
`Y axis MR1` <- matrix(cbind(`Chord height at R42000`[1:length(`Chord height at R42000`)-1], 
    `Chord height at R42000`[2:length(`Chord height at R42000`)]), ncol = 2)
`MR chart` <- qcc(`Y axis MR1`, type = "R", nsigmas = (NSigmas / 2), xlab = "Observations", 
    ylab = "Moving range", title = "Moving range Chart", digits = `Significant algharisms`)
CapabilidadeI1 <- process.capability(`I1 chart`, spec.limits = c(1198, 1211), 
    nsigmas = (NSigmas / 2), target = ((1198 + 1211) / 2))

dev.off()
```

---

### Spreadsheet1 - Rename it for "Finish - Chord height at R42000".

```
Number  Defect
2       1204
5       1198
9       1205
1       1201
4       1198
3       1204
6       1207
8       1201
10      1197
11      1203
12      1199
13      1204
14      1204
19      1208
22      1197
28      1202
30      1209
24      1205
21      1202
25      1202
20      1204
26      1200
65      1205
```

Comment: share the code where you used which() and subset(). Also share a sample of your data(not as an image) such that we can directly work on it! And just to get it right, if the user enters 5, then the #defects corresponding to material nbr=5 is what you want right ?

Comment: Thank you for your advice sir. I made changes in the question.

Comment: so if the user enters 65, you want 1205?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dt=fread("Number  Defect
2       1204
5       1198
9       1205
1       1201
4       1198
3       1204
6       1207
8       1201
10      1197
11      1203
12      1199
13      1204
14      1204
19      1208
22      1197
28      1202
30      1209
24      1205
21      1202
25      1202
20      1204
26      1200
65       1205")

d = scan(n=5)
1: 3
2: 7
3: 11
4: 65
5: 20
Read 5 items
> d
[1]  3  7 11 65 20

dt[which(dt$Number %in% d),]
   Number Defect
1:      3   1204
2:     11   1203
3:     20   1204
4:     65   1205
```

'7' didn't have the corresponding defect so didn't appear

Comment: Thank you very much @joel.wilson. This tip worked with some changes.